# Knitr + Beamer to PDF: Incorrect Font Symbols

Tags: pdf, fonts, latex, knitr, beamer

I'm using TexStudio 2.8.4 to create a pdf containing knitr output and I'm running into issues with symbols showing up incorrectly either in the pdf or when copy and pasted from the pdf. Here's a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        <<>>=
        #dollar$sign
        if(2+2 == 4){print("math")}
        @
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In my pdf output, the `$` in the commented out font shows up as the pound (currency) sign, but when copy and pasted shows up correctly as a dollar sign. This does not occur when it is not commented out.

More problematically, while the braces `{}` appear correct in the pdf output, when copied and pasted they are `f` and `g`. This confusion does not affect R's interpretation of the braces, however.

Do you have any thoughts/suggestions for fixing this? As a work around, I'm just using a non-echoed knitr block and using a latex verbatim environment for the code on the front side, though this is not ideal.

The command I'm using in my custom build is:

```
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/bin/Rscript.exe" -e "library(knitr); knit2pdf('%.Rnw')" | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | "C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" "?am.pdf"
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with LaTeX encoding. The solution is adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17858/37118).